# How does laravel handle session id?

Tags: php, laravel, security, session, web

specifically where is the session id ,on client-side, going to be saved?
in cookie or in hidden form input,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In PHP, by default session data is stored in files on the server. Each file is named after a cookie that is stored on the client computer. This session cookie (PHPSESSID) presumably survives on the client side until all windows of the browser are closed.

You can check `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` for `session.save_path`, usually in /tmp

Answer (score 0):

according to session.php file in config folder u can see:

```
|Session Cookie Name
|Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
```

so it clarify that session id is stored in the cookie and here u can change the cookie name.
a useful related link:
https://dev.to/zubairmohsin33/laravel-s-default-cookies-and-where-to-find-them-54bg